# Tomcat/JBoss Remove SSL and force new handshake

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jboss

Does anyone know how to remove an SSL certificate from the user's session and force the SSL handshake to be completed again?

I've tried removing the cert by calling

```
request.removeAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. In fact the code seems to ignore that property.

Comment: For what purpose? You'll only get the same certificate again via the new handshake, unless something has happened to the certs installed at the browser end.

Answer (score 1):

The code that gets the certificate ultimately calls [`org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(...)`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSESupport.java). However, the re-negotiation is only triggered if a certificate hasn't already been associated with the session:

```
if(jsseCerts.length <= 0 && force) {
    session.invalidate();
    handShake();
    session = ssl.getSession();
}
```

Therefore, since you already have a certificate with the `SSLSession` (and since removing the attribute from the request will have no effect on this), you won't be able to trigger a re-negotiation that will make you forget that certificate.

You may find your need to patch the implementation of various classes in Tomcat (that call `getPeerCertificateChain`) to achieve this. That's what you need to do if you want to perform an "SSL logout" (which is similar).
You may be able to ask the client to close the connection (and thus create a new connection it would negotiate without client certificate) by using the `Connection: close` HTTP header. However, since it's normally up to the closing party to send it, it's not guaranteed that the recipient (the client) will close it (and again, as far as I know, there's nothing in the Servlet specification, nor in the Tomcat implementation, that allows use to force the closure of the connection).

Answer (score 1):

These are two different questions.

1. The attribute is only there for Servlets and filters to use. Tomcat doesn't use it, in fact it doesn't really care about the certificate once an SSL session exists and authentication has succeeded. You can remove the attribute but you're only fooling yourself really,
2. If you can both invalidate the SSL session and request a new handshake, a new certificate will be delivered anyway, probably the same one unless something has happened to the browser certs in the meantime. That will overwrite the request attribute, so you didn't really need to clear it in the first place. However I'm not aware of any way you can invalidate SSL sessions or rehandshake in Tomcat, short of providing your own SSL connector with an API to do so that is reachable by Servlets or filters, and I don't know how to do that either.

You could always tell us your *requirement.*